# Texworks is not compiling!

Tags: miktex, compiling, texworks

I've installed the MikTeX and Texworks in a new computer, but when I run my project here it doesn't work...

The error message that I got is the following:

```
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Ray/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/initexmf.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you
need help.

Sorry, but C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\miktex-pdftex.exe did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:/Users/Ray/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-pdftex.log

You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page (http://miktex.org), if you need help.
```

The log file message from initexmf.log is shown below:

```
2015-10-28 12:20:00,463-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration >Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:20:00,471-0200 INFO  initexmf - Registering root directories...
2015-10-28 12:20:08,346-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration >Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:20:08,355-0200 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-28 12:20:08,355-0200 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-28 12:20:08,357-0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-28 12:20:08,386-0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2015-10-28 12:20:14,295-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:20:14,315-0200 INFO  initexmf - Making format links...
2015-10-28 12:20:14,516-0200 INFO  initexmf - Making script links...
2015-10-28 12:20:14,918-0200 INFO  initexmf -   C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\miktex-taskbar-icon.exe
2015-10-28 12:20:14,988-0200 INFO  initexmf -   C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\miktex-update.exe
2015-10-28 12:20:16,475-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:20:16,486-0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def...
2015-10-28 12:20:16,587-0200 INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --verbose --admin
2015-10-28 12:22:31,682-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:22:33,043-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:22:34,393-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:22:34,425-0200 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-28 12:22:34,425-0200 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-28 12:22:34,429-0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-10-28 12:22:34,467-0200 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2015-10-28 12:22:44,432-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:22:46,896-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:22:48,890-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:25:05,015-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:25:05,031-0200 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo
015-10-28 12:25:05,031-0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\6c9a5fc74f51ce24ff6764843c117e40.fndb
2015-10-28 12:25:05,031-0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-10-28 12:25:05,031-0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
2015-10-28 12:25:07,069-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:25:07,069-0200 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.

2015-10-28 12:25:07,069-0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\6c9a5fc74f51ce24ff6764843c117e40.fndb
2015-10-28 12:25:07,069-0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-10-28 12:25:07,069-0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
2015-10-28 12:28:56,691-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:28:56,785-0200 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.

2015-10-28 12:28:56,785-0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\6c9a5fc74f51ce24ff6764843c117e40.fndb
2015-10-28 12:28:56,785-0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-10-28 12:28:56,785-0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
2015-10-28 12:40:20,070-0200 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-10-28 12:40:20,083-0200 FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo.

2015-10-28 12:40:20,083-0200 FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\Ray\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\6c9a5fc74f51ce24ff6764843c117e40.fndb
2015-10-28 12:40:20,083-0200 FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
2015-10-28 12:40:20,083-0200 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
```

And the log message from miktex-pdftex.log is shown below:

```
2015-10-28 12:25:06,473-0200 INFO  miktex-pdftex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2015-10-28 12:25:07,106-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The operation failed for some reason.
2015-10-28 12:25:07,106-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe
2015-10-28 12:25:07,106-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2015-10-28 12:25:07,107-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 290
2015-10-28 12:28:55,832-0200 INFO  miktex-pdftex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2015-10-28 12:28:56,816-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The operation failed for some reason.
2015-10-28 12:28:56,816-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe
2015-10-28 12:28:56,816-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2015-10-28 12:28:56,816-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 290
2015-10-28 12:40:19,464-0200 INFO  miktex-pdftex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2015-10-28 12:40:20,105-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - The operation failed for some reason.
2015-10-28 12:40:20,105-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Info: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe
2015-10-28 12:40:20,105-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process.cpp
2015-10-28 12:40:20,105-0200 FATAL miktex-pdftex - Line: 290
```

I don't know what's happening, what could I do to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps try compiling from the command line first. Anyway you'll have more explicit messages.

Comment: So what does that log file say?

Comment: @Bernard I didn't understand what you mean in "compiling from the command line first", how can I do that?

Comment: @WaynerKlën: The error message shows the exact path of (two) log-files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I've edited the question with the log files messages.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I've edited the question to insert the message from log files! :)

Comment: Use the code buttom to format the logs. They are unreadable.

Comment: @Wayner Klën: I meant  opening a command prompt in the directory of a file you want to compile, say foo.tex  and type `pdflatex foo.tex`. Recently some similar problems were solved this way. Also, after the installation, did you run `MiKTeX Update`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I fixed the formatting, easier to read now.

Comment: @Bernard I've updated the miktex, and now the texworks is compiling, but  I'm still having problems with my labguage packages.... So it's not finishing

Comment: Is `lubguage` a portmanteau word made up from language and luggage ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Close TexWorks and go to `C:\Users\$user_name$\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\data\le` and delete all .fndb files. Reopen TexWorks and it should compile without problems.

replace $user_name$ with your username.

Comment: This did not work for me, the exact same error occurs before and after deleting the .fndb files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a new user and I get the exact same error message when trying to compile an example from the tutorial. It really feels like there is something wrong with this installer. I removed the .fndb files (as someone mentioned) and the initial error got resolved, but when trying to compile a colleagues file, in the same root folder and which I now for a fact is functioning on his machine, is just renders a cascade of error messages. People tell me this system is the most robust for typesetting. Well, my first impression is not the best.

Have I done something wrong or is there a huge bug in the Basic MikTeX 2.9.5721 Installer?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does compiling a basic hello world example work? I.e. `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello world!\end{document}` I don't know which system your colleague has, but there is a chance that he has older packages, and that there has been breaking changes between the version(s) he has and the ones you have. However, if you want help resolving that, please ask a new question, with more details about the code and errors. This site doesn't work like a normal forum, so answers to a "thread" are reserved for actual answers to the problem posed in the initial post.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that out and report in a new question. However, if new users that download this installer end up with the same error message, I figured it could be of interest to developers. It usually is the case. Thanks for the help